# ASP.NET forms AjaxFileUpload triggering updatePanel issue

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I'm trying to understand how I can get the "UploadedCompleteAll" event of a AjaxFileUpload control (http://www.asp.net/AjaxLibrary/AjaxControlToolkitSampleSite/AjaxFileUpload/AjaxFileUpload.aspx) to trigger a update on a updatePanel as to display a list of files uploaded by the user including the latest upload.

**Currently the update is never triggered and displayed to the users screen**

My code is as the following:

.aspx

```
 <asp:Content ID="Content3" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">
  <asp:AjaxFileUpload id="videoUpload" runat="server"
                MaximumNumberOfFiles="5"
                OnUploadComplete="ajaxVideoUpload_OnUploadComplete"
                OnUploadCompleteAll="ajaxVideoUpload_OnUploadCompleteAll"
                ThrobberID="ThrobberImg"
                />

            <asp:Image
                id="ThrobberImg"
                ImageUrl="~/Images/ajax-loader.gif"
                Style="display:None"
                runat="server" />
        <asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" id="uploadedVid" UpdateMode="Always">
            <ContentTemplate>
            <asp:Repeater id="uploadedVideoFiles" runat="server">
                <HeaderTemplate></HeaderTemplate>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <div class="videoDisplayBox">
                        <h2 id="videoTitle" runat="server"><%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem ,"fileName")%></h2>
                        <asp:Image runat="server" id="videoImage"></asp:Image>
                    </div>
                </ItemTemplate>
                <FooterTemplate></FooterTemplate>
            </asp:Repeater>
            </ContentTemplate>

            </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

.aspx.cs

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        AjaxControlToolkit.ToolkitScriptManager.GetCurrent(this).RegisterAsyncPostBackControl(videoUpload);
        uploadedVideoFiles.DataSource = MiddleTier.MySession.Current.MyPerson.AllVideoUploads;
        uploadedVideoFiles.DataBind();
    }
    protected void ajaxVideoUpload_OnUploadComplete(Object sender, AjaxControlToolkit.AjaxFileUploadEventArgs e)
    {
        // Generate file path
        TTPerson person = MiddleTier.MySession.Current.MyPerson;
        string clubUid = MiddleTier.MySession.Current.MyPerson.MyClub.Uid.ToString();
        string filePath  = "~/VideoUpload/" + clubUid+ Convert.ToString(e.FileName);
        string extension = System.IO.Path.GetExtension(e.FileName);
       //following lines are saving to our database
        TTPage curPage = this.Page as TTPage;
        TTFileUploadVideo fileUploadVid = new TTFileUploadVideo(JadeSoftware.Joob.ClassPersistence.Transient);
        fileUploadVid.FileName = e.FileName;
        fileUploadVid.FileType = extension;
        fileUploadVid.MyUploader = person;
        fileUploadVid.UploadTimeStamp = System.DateTime.Now;
        fileUploadVid.MyFileUploadGroup = null;
        AC_TTFileUploadVideo ac = new AC_TTFileUploadVideo(curPage.connection, fileUploadVid, curPage, true);
        ac.Create();
        //savign to databse ends here
        videoUpload.SaveAs(MapPath(filePath));
    }

    protected void ajaxVideoUpload_OnUploadCompleteAll(Object sender, AjaxControlToolkit.AjaxFileUploadCompleteAllEventArgs e)
    {
        uploadedVideoFiles.DataSource = MiddleTier.MySession.Current.MyPerson.AllVideoUploads;
        uploadedVideoFiles.DataBind();
    }
```

webconfig section for AjaxFileUpload

```
  <system.web>     
  <pages>
  <controls>
    <add tagPrefix="ajaxToolkit" assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" />
  </controls>
</pages></system.web>
<system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" />
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false"/>
    <handlers>
        <add name="AjaxFileUploadHandler" verb="*" path="AjaxFileUploadHandler.axd" type="AjaxControlToolkit.AjaxFileUploadHandler, AjaxControlToolkit"/>
    </handlers>
    <security>
        <requestFiltering>
            <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="4294967295"/>
        </requestFiltering>
    </security>
</system.webServer>
```

any help would be greatly appreciated!

Cheers
Tim

Comment: Where are you actually placing the `AjaxFileUpload` control? I don't see it in the code snippets you provided.

Comment: not sure why it wasnt displaying the snippet correctly, added another space and hopefully its there now above the Image control

Comment: Yes, it's displaying now. Your `AjaxFileUpload` control is outside the `UpdatePanel`, therefore it should not cause an update to your `UpdatePanel`. However, the `AjaxFileUpload` control is an Ajax control itself so you don't actually need an UpdatePanel. The only thing I can think of is that you might not have added the handler to your web.config as describer in the `AjaxFileUpload Handler` section in the URL you provided.

Comment: Thanks Bokonja, i've added the webconfig i currently have, my understanding is its correct and the actual ajaxfileupload is working correctly just unable to update the list of uploaded files once all uploads are completed on the completeAll event. should the following `AjaxControlToolkit.ToolkitScriptManager.GetCurrent(this).RegisterAsyncPostBackControl(videoUpload);` have registered the event so even though the control is outside the updatePanel the panel update should still be triggered? Appreciate the help!

Comment: Okay, let me give out an idea I have as to what you might be doing which might be way off track, but let's try it out. The AjaxFileUpload control has server and client side handlers. You want the serverside events to trigger so as to save the files AND you want the clientside events to fire to actually show that the upload was successfull. You don't have any clientside event handlers. Try forgetting about the updatePanel and adding the clientside handlers (OnClientUploadComplete namely) because that should be the part where you do client side stuff.

Comment: Just to clarify, using the client side event i'd drop the concept of using a updatePanel and instead do something along the lines of a ajax call inside the method defined by the `OnClientUploadComplete` property to get the latest file data and update the DOM client side?

Comment: I ended up using the client side event, and writing some javascript to update the list instead of doing it serverside. Thanks for your help, if you want to make an answer I can rate it so you get the rep. Cheers Tim

Comment: Sorry, went to sleep in the meantime, but I'm glad you were still able to get it to work. I'm actually more curious first if the server side event of the `AjaxFileUpload` control is fired or did you really need to write an AJAX call in client-side events? I've never actually used the control, but it looked to me like the server-side events should have been silently done via AJAX or something like that.

Comment: Will have to investigate more, and get back to you. For now its working with the Ajax implementation on client side event